# Proof: $R\subseteq A$ is closed $\iff$ There is $S\subseteq X$ s.t $R=S\cap A$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a topologic space, and $A\subseteq X$
then $R\subseteq A$ is closed in $A$ $\iff$ there is $S\subseteq X$ closed s.t $R=S\cap A$

$\Rightarrow:$ Let there $S\subseteq X$ be closed in $X$ then, $S^{C_X}$ is open, then $S^{C_X}\cap A$ is open as intersection of two open sets and $(S^{C_X}\cap A)^{C_A}$ is closed in $A$

$\Leftarrow:$ $R^{C_A}=(S\cap A)^{C_A}=S^{C_A}\cup A^{C_A}$, $S$ is closed then $S^{C_A}$ is open,  $A^{C_A}=\emptyset$ which is too, open. a union of finite set is open then $R^{C_A}$ is open, and $R$ is closed in $A$.

Is the proof valid?

Comment: in the first direction ($\Rightarrow$) are you assuming that $A$ is open?

Comment: @Giulio Yes it is in the topologic space of $X$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is wrong. I think you have interchange the conditions.

$(\Longrightarrow )$ As $R$ is closed in $A$, then $R^{C_A}$ is open in A. Then $\exists G $ open in $X$ with $R^{C_A}=G\cap A$. Therefore $R=(G\cap A)^{C_A}=G^{C_A}\cup A^{C_A}=G^{C_A}=G^{C_X}\cap A$. Taking $S=G^{C_X}$ closed in $X$, we have that $R=S\cap A$.

$(\Longleftarrow)$ $R=S\cap A$ with $S$ closed in $X$. Then $R^{C_A}=(S\cap A)^{C_A}=S^{C_A}\cup A^{C_A}=S^{C_A}=S^{C_X}\cap A$. As $S^{C_X}$ is open in $X$, $R^{C_A}$ is open in $A$. Therefore $R$ is closed in $A$.

**Obs:**
In this type of exercise it is conviniently to specify 'where' are the subsets open or closed in each step.